# Issue with Ember.js child route not rendering and parent route being called at the same time

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having an issue getting the template to display after the route changes. The log states that I've transitioned into form.newrecord but the template isn't rendering.

**Routers:**

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('home', { path: '/' });
    this.resource('form', { path: '/forms/:form_id' }, function() {
        this.route('newrecord', { path: '/newrecord' });
    });
});

App.FormNewRecordRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("form/newrecord", { 
            into: "application",
            outlet: "newrecord"
     })}
});
```

**Templates:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
    {{outlet newrecord}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="form">
    <h1>Test 2</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="form/newrecord">
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's definitely a capitalization issue.  Just switch to this and you should be fine : `App.FormNewrecordRoute`

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1100/edit

Comment: This is great Jeremy. I must have misred the Ember forums and didn't realize that the casing mattered after the initial capital.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, perhaps there is just a naming issue here.

You have defined `App.FormNewRecordRoute` (with capital R) and `this.route('newrecord')` with lower r. Try to make them consistent to see if it works.